# # in hyperlink prevent the copy of full hyperlink

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I have made a macro that is copying over hyperlinks from one column to another.

Macro works just fine however **hyperlinks contain '#' in the middle of them** so lets say:

```
https://website.com/nu#somethingsomething
```

which makes the macro copy just first part of it i.e.:

```
https://website.com/nu
```

Any ideas how to make Excel ignore '#' (if possible at all) and **copy the entire value of hyperlink**?

VBA code:

```
Sub MilestonesHyperlink()

For i = 2 To 62 'Number of rows

If Range("B" & i).Value <> "" And Range("A" & i).Value <> "" Then 'Copy from column B to A

    Dim newLink As String

    If Range("B" & i).Hyperlinks.Count = 1 Then
    newLink = Range("B" & i).Hyperlinks(1).Address
    Range("A" & i).Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=Range("A" & i), Address:=Range("A" & i)
    Range("A" & i).Hyperlinks(1).Address = newLink
    End If
End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the `newlink` with:

```
newLink = Range("B" & i).Hyperlinks(1).Address + "#" + Range("B" & i).Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress
```